# While loop with input() python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get this code to work but somehow it is not working

I want to check the user input (it has to match to my list of train stations)

I supposed to use a while loop till the user uses a correct train station and then continue to question 2

First input is: depart station?
Second input (second question): arrive station?

this is my code so far:

```
stations = ["Schagen", "Heerhugowaard", "Alkmaar", "Castricum", "Zaandam", "Amsterdam Sloterdijk", "Amsterdam Centraal",
        "Amsterdam Amstel", "Utrecht Centraal", "Hertogenbosch", "Eindhoven", "Weert", "Roermond", "Sittard",
        "Maastricht"]
start = input("Wat is je begin station?")
end = input("Wat is je eind station?")

if start in stations:
    print('Je vertrekt vanaf:', start)
else:
    print("wrong station")
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: first of all i hope someone can help me to add a while loop to check the user input.

with the code above if i typ a correct station it still says wrong station..

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is not homework, as you should be attempting to solve those with documentation (https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

I would try something like this.. though it could be made nicer by allowing for selection of station by number or fuzzy matching the strings.

```
stations = ["Schagen", "Heerhugowaard", "Alkmaar", "Castricum", "Zaandam", "Amsterdam Sloterdijk", "Amsterdam Centraal","Amsterdam Amstel", "Utrecht Centraal", "Hertogenbosch", "Eindhoven", "Weert",  "Roermond", "Sittard","Maastricht"]

print "Stations"
for i in range(len(stations)):
     print(str(i) + " " + stations[i])

start = input("Wat is je begin station?")
while start not in stations:
        print("wrong station")
        start = input("Wat is je begin station?")

print('Je vertrekt vanaf: {0}'.format(start))

end = input("Wat is je eind station?")
while end not in stations:
       print("wrong station")
      end = input("Wat is je eind station?")

print('Je aankomt op: {0}'.format(end))
```

Comment: Thnx! last quesion: I want to print: Je vertrekt van start en je eindstation is end. How to combine these at the end?

Comment: print("Je vertrekt van {0} en je eindstation is {1}".format(start,end))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stations = ["Schagen", "Heerhugowaard", "Alkmaar", "Castricum", "Zaandam", "Amsterdam Sloterdijk", "Amsterdam Centraal",
        "Amsterdam Amstel", "Utrecht Centraal", "Hertogenbosch", "Eindhoven", "Weert", "Roermond", "Sittard",
        "Maastricht"]
mapped = [x.lower().strip() for x in stations] # lowercased stations
start = input("Wat is je begin station?").lower().strip()

while not start.lower().strip() in mapped:
    print("wrong station")
    start = input("Wat is je begin station?").lower().strip()
start = stations[mapped.index(start)]

end = input("Wat is je eind station?").lower().strip()
print('Je vertrekt vanaf:', start)

while not end in stations:
    print("wrong station")
    end = input("Wat is je eind station?").lower().strip()

end = stations[mapped.index(start)]
# print the end station here.
```

Comment: it still says wrong station,

I want to get this:

start station: Alkmaar -> it is a match go to the second question -> End station? also a match -> print Your start is Amsterdam en your end station is Eindhoven

But if the user makes a typo then ask the question until the user has entered the correct station, i suppose you can do this with a while loop?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: try this: `print(repr(start))` after the first `input` statement. Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
questions = {1: "Wat is je begin station?", 2: "Wat is je eind station?"}
ques_number = 1     

while ques_number<=2:
  answer = input(questions[ques_number])
  if answer in stations:
    print('Je vertrekt vanaf:%s'%answer)
    ques_number += 1
  else:
    print("wrong station")
```

This would keep asking the user for stations. You can increase the no. of questions as required.

Comment: Why the ugly incrementing? How about using a question list and a for loop instead?

Comment: it still says wrong station, I want to get this: start station: Alkmaar -> it is a match go to the second question -> End station? also a match -> print Your start is Amsterdam en your end station is Eindhoven But if the user makes a typo then ask the question until the user has entered the correct station, i suppose you can do this with a while loop?

Comment: Because you need to increment only when the answer is correct. Or else keep asking the same question.